# iOS Content Blocker not working on iPad (fine on iPhone)

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, safari, safari-content-blocker

I have just made an Content Blocker to block some information in Safari (something like adBlock, but not block ad), and **everything works fine on iPhone Simulator and my iPhone 6S**, but though I can open the content blocker in Settings -> Safari -> Content Blockers, **nothing happened in Safari on iPad Simulator and my iPad mini 2**, somebody know why?

(Xcode 7.1 + iOS 9.1 + Swift 2.1)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: got any solution? i have same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865806/content-blocker-works-in-simulator-but-does-not-work-in-iphone-device

Answer (score 2):

Consider these:

- Content blockers require 64bit CPU (String matching isn't fast enough on 32bits). You should check if iPad simulator simulates 32 bit.
- Content blockers doesn't work on cached data, because Safari won't send http request for it. Best way to verify is to open in 'private browsing mode'.