# content blocker works in simulator but does not work in iPhone device

Tags: ios, swift, safari-extension, safari-content-blocker

i am working on content blocker and block the adult site so, this code is perfect work on simulator when i test on iPhone 6 then its no one site is block

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

                self.containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.domainName.contentBlocker")
                let path = self.containerURL?.appendingPathComponent("blockerList.json")

                self.text = utf8Text.description
                do {

                    try self.text.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                print(path)

            }
        }
```

Then after load data on extension handler file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Below is the link of Github code:
**https://github.com/krishkumar/BlockParty** Have a look at it, may be it can help you out.

Comment: @jiten i already use it but it also not working in real device.

Comment: The fact that it works in the simulator but not on a device might indicate an entitlement / code signing issue. Make sure that both of your targets (app and extension) have App Groups turned on and declare membership in the correct group.

Comment: @Jiri without app group its not work in simulator app group(ON) is compulsory for both simulator and real device i also test it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where reading the contents of the group directly worked on the simulator, but not on a device. It resolved this by creating a subdirectory in the group and do all reading writing in this subdirectory.

```
if let root = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "YOUR_GROUP_NAME") {
    let url = root.appendingPathComponent("storage")
    try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

    let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator()
    var error: NSError?
    fileCoordinator.coordinate(readingItemAt: url, options: .withoutChanges, error: &error) { url in

        if let urls = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.canonicalPathKey], options: []) {
            for u in urls {
                 print("\(u.standardizedFileURL)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```